# Azure vm docker create cannot find certificate 'ca.pem'

Tags: azure, openssl, docker, azure-cli

I'm trying to create a docker host in azure, so I ran the following command (via [azure-cli](http://msopentech.com/blog/2014/08/07/azure-cross-platform-cli-tools/) version 0.8.11 and node version 0.10.33):

```
$ azure vm docker create -v [.. + loads of options..]
info:    Executing command vm docker create
verbose: C:\Users\JAM\.docker\ca-key.pem file was not found
verbose: C:\Users\JAM\.docker\ca.pem file was not found
verbose: C:\Users\JAM\.docker\server-key.pem file was not found
verbose: C:\Users\JAM\.docker\server-cert.pem file was not found
verbose: C:\Users\JAM\.docker\key.pem file was not found
verbose: C:\Users\JAM\.docker\cert.pem file was not found
verbose: Generating docker certificates.
verbose: Loading 'screen' into random state - done
Generating RSA private key, 512 bit long modulus
.......++++++++++++
............++++++++++++
e is 65537 (0x10001)

verbose: Unable to load config info from /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf

verbose: Loading 'screen' into random state - done
Generating RSA private key, 512 bit long modulus
.++++++++++++
..++++++++++++
e is 65537 (0x10001)

verbose: Unable to load config info from /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf

verbose: Loading 'screen' into random state -C:\Users\JAM\.docker\server.csr: No such file or directory
 done

verbose: Loading 'screen' into random state - done
Generating RSA private key, 512 bit long modulus
.........................++++++++++++
..++++++++++++
e is 65537 (0x10001)

verbose: Unable to load config info from /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf

verbose: Loading 'screen' into random state -C:\Users\JAM\.docker\client.csr: No such file or directory
 done

verbose: writing RSA key

verbose: writing RSA key

error:   ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\JAM\.docker\ca.pem'
verbose: stack Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\JAM\.docker\ca.pem'
    at Object.fs.chmodSync (fs.js:832:18)
    at C:\nvm\v0.10.33\node_modules\azure-cli\lib\commands\asm\vm\vmclient.js:3104:30
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\nvm\v0.10.33\node_modules\azure-cli\node_modules\openssl-wrapper\lib\openssl-wrapper.js:86:16)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
info:    Error information has been recorded to azure.err
```

The azure-cli is unable to load the openssl config, because the path `/usr/local` does not exist:

```
verbose: Unable to load config info from /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

However, the path `/usr/ssl/..` and `/usr/ssl/openssl.cnf` exists. So I tried just copying `/usr/ssl/*` to `/usr/local/ssl/*`, but the same error keeps popping up.

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been open for a while, but the bottom line is that the Windows support is pretty half baked.  The best thing to do is to download OpenSSL and then generate the required key files using the following commands (copy the resulting files to the .docker folder in your error).

```
echo 01 > ca.srl

openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca-key.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key ca-key.pem -out ca.pem
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server-key.pem
openssl req -new -key server-key.pem -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -out server-cert.pem

echo "Creating client keys..."
openssl genrsa -des3 -out client-key.pem
openssl req -new -key client-key.pem -out client.csr
echo extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth > extfile.cnf
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in client.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -out client-cert.pem -extfile extfile.cnf

echo "Stripping passwords from keys..."
openssl rsa -in server-key.pem -out server-key.pem
openssl rsa -in client-key.pem -out key.pem
```

This was originally lifted from: http://blog.jameskyle.org/2014/04/coreos-docker-remote-api-tls/ which is aimed primarily at unix but the commands are effectively the same on Windows.

Once you have copied these files into the right place you can progress your install (I'm current trying to troubleshoot the next step :)).